# How to use an input array for drawing a graph in GraphView Library?

Tags: android, audio, audio-recording, android-graphview

I am developing an Android application,which can take audio input from device mic and generate a graph in real time as an output.For generating a Graph on a view I am using [GraphView library](http://www.android-graphview.org/download-getting-started/).
I am trying to convert a .wav audio file into an array.But I don't know where I have to use this array for drawing a graph?

Comment: What have you tried so far ? If you have code, please paste it here for others to look at.

Comment: i found this : 1 - create a WaveSimple (time, amplitude);

Comment: I have updated misleading description as well as title. Now anyone can easily understand what exactly the question is.

Thanks.

Comment: @Adib Which library you are using for drawing graph? If it is http://www.android-graphview.org/download-getting-started/ then you can easily find mutiple samples on the same link.

Comment: @AdarshYadav I want to use GraphView library, but i din't know what it not working. if you want i can show you my code

Answer (score 0):

i found this : 
1 - create a WaveSimple (time, amplitude)
then i creat a Liste to add samples in this Liste;

```
Liste<WaveSample> pointListe = new ArrayListe<>();
```

and when i start recording i put this :

```
pointList.add(new WaveSample (Time, myAudioRecord.getMaxAmplitude ());
```

i want to create a lineGraph with this List but i couldn't ; 
this what i write :

```
for(int i = 0; i<pointList.size(); i++){
    x = (double) pointList.getTime();
    y = (double) pointList.getAmplitude();
   series.appendData(new DataPoint(x, y),true,pointList.size())
   }
```

but doesnt work